# How can plug 2 external monitors in 1 USB-C?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dock, usb-c

I want to have 2 external monitors showing different workspaces. I don't want to replicate screens.

Is this possible with 2 HDMI displays?

I found this dock: [Asus Universal USB-C dock](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks-Accessory/Universal-Dock/) solution with a VGA and HDMI output. Does this dock serve my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it does not support dual monitor output.

> HDMI and VGA port can't be displayed at the same time.

This product will not do what you want.

[This is an USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter that would work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BPEV1XK) but you would need two of them.

Comment: Make sure to count the available ports : USB 3 standard rectangular port is different from the USB C rounded port.